How does additive animation work in practice?
According to this Anim Coding tutorial:

In additive animations, additional movements are layered on top of existing animations. This allows for complex actions to be created without the need for entirely new animation clips, enhancing the richness of the animation without significantly increasing the workload for animators.

How does additive animation work in practice?

There are some good examples of how additive animations were used in the Uncharted games in this GDC talk. They used them for aiming, adding spine bends and twists to make overridden limbs in layered animations look less robotic, and to add variety to idle poses and walk/run cycles. (If anyone would like to use this link and expand it into an Answer post, they would be most welcome - I just won't have time to do so for at least a day or two)
